# paste0 for a specified 3 columns within a loop

Tags: r, data.table

```
df<-data.frame(expand.grid(c("a","b","c"),c("p","q","r"),c("x","y","z"),c("l","m","n")));
```

I have this table which has 4 columns, I would like to have the results in a vector such that it should be

```
paste0(df$Var1,df$Var2,df$Var4)
```

Question asked here is just for a demonstration purpose, so I would like this to be very dynamic and flexible.

I am looking for any code which can concatenate 2, 3 or 4 columns as specified.

If let's say

```
i<-1;
j<-2;
k<-4;
paste0(df[,i],df[,j],df[,k])
```

Now imagine doing the same if there are many columns in a df. also the numbers of columns and which of those columns should be based on input.

I would appreciate if this is done using a data.table package.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you’ve attempted and why it didn’t work? This will help us more accurately answer your question

Comment: Why are you wrapping in `data.frame`? The call to `expand.grid(.)` already returns a frame.

Comment: r2evans. I am happy to do it without data frame. I wanted something else actually. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Mohit r2evnas edited his answer to demonstrate on `data.table`, `df[, do.call(paste0, .SD)]` If you need to select columns you can use `df[, do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = your_vector_of_columns]`

Comment: Gregor, thanks a lot for reply. let me check this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need `do.call`.

```r
df <- expand.grid(c("a","b","c"),c("p","q","r"),c("x","y","z"))
do.call(paste0, df)
#  [1] "apx" "bpx" "cpx" "aqx" "bqx" "cqx" "arx" "brx" "crx" "apy" "bpy" "cpy" "aqy" "bqy" "cqy" "ary" "bry" "cry" "apz" "bpz" "cpz" "aqz" "bqz" "cqz" "arz"
# [26] "brz" "crz"
```

Since you mentioned `data.table`, let me build the right object then:

```r
library(data.table)
# option 1
df <- data.table(expand.grid(c("a","b","c"),c("p","q","r"),c("x","y","z")))
# option 2
df <- expand.grid(c("a","b","c"),c("p","q","r"),c("x","y","z"))
setDT(df)

# then
df[, do.call(paste0, .SD)]
#  [1] "apx" "bpx" "cpx" "aqx" "bqx" "cqx" "arx" "brx" "crx" "apy" "bpy" "cpy" "aqy" "bqy" "cqy" "ary" "bry" "cry" "apz" "bpz" "cpz" "aqz" "bqz" "cqz" "arz"
# [26] "brz" "crz"
```

With `data.table`'s `.SD` you can specify certain columns, e.g., `df[, do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = c(i, j, k)]`.

---

Your need to choose columns is just a column-subset, ala `df[,c(1,2,4)]`.

```r
df <- expand.grid(c("a","b","c"),c("p","q","r"),c("x","y","z"),c("l","m","n"))
i <- 1
j <- 2
k <- 4
do.call(paste0, df[,c(i, j, k)])
#  [1] "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl" "brl" "crl" "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl" "brl" "crl" "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl"
# [26] "brl" "crl" "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm"
# [51] "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn" "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn" "apn" "bpn" "cpn"
# [76] "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn"
```

and as GregorThomas said in a comment, the `data.table`-form for this is:

```r
as.data.table(df)[, do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = c(i, j, k)]
```

Comment: Please if you could revise your answer. I have edited the question

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `Reduce()`:

```r
df <-
  data.frame(expand.grid(c("a", "b", "c"), c("p", "q", "r"), c("x", "y", "z")))

df_pasted <- Reduce(paste0, df)
df_pasted
#>  [1] "apx" "bpx" "cpx" "aqx" "bqx" "cqx" "arx" "brx" "crx" "apy" "bpy" "cpy"
#> [13] "aqy" "bqy" "cqy" "ary" "bry" "cry" "apz" "bpz" "cpz" "aqz" "bqz" "cqz"
#> [25] "arz" "brz" "crz"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

EDIT: As noted by r2evans, you can just specify which columns you want to keep. If you have a `data.table` you can use:

```
Reduce(paste0, df[, .(i, j, k), with = FALSE])
```

Comment: This works well, and I encourage people to play with `Reduce` to learn how it can be used effectively. In this case, it calls `paste0` a total of `n-1` times (where `n` is the number of columns). In contrast, using `do.call(paste0, ..)` calls it _once_. If the OP is dealing with _a heckuva lot_ of data and/or long strings, then this starts to have a little bit of a deleterious effect on R's performance in light of R's global string pool: by building `"px"` and then `"apx"` in this example, we really never need the intermediate `"px"` and never see it, but it uses memory anyway.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for pointing out the performance implications of `Reduce()`!

Comment: code should be such that columns should be user defined. so if I have a dataframe of around 10 columns, and out of these if 3 needs to be concatenated. those 3 columns can be at any place.

Comment: Please see edited question above and please if you can rebuild your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `interaction` like below (if you don't want to produce a expanded grid by `expand.grid`)

```
> lst <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("p", "q", "r"), c("x", "y", "z"))

> levels(interaction(lst, sep = ""))
 [1] "apx" "bpx" "cpx" "aqx" "bqx" "cqx" "arx" "brx" "crx" "apy" "bpy" "cpy"
[13] "aqy" "bqy" "cqy" "ary" "bry" "cry" "apz" "bpz" "cpz" "aqz" "bqz" "cqz"
[25] "arz" "brz" "crz"
```

Comment: This doesn't work the same on a subset; compare `levels(interaction(df[1:5,], sep = ""))` with `paste0(df$Var1[1:5], df$Var2[1:5], df$Var3[1:5])`. This is because it's expanding to all _possible_ combinations of the three variables, not the _observed_ combinations. Perhaps that's always the case with the OP, that may need to be a stated assumption in the question?

Comment: @r2evans aha, you are right that it doesn't work for subsets. I just updated my answer if OP is not start from `expand.grid`, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of solving this problem for an undetermined number of columns is to rewrite the code in other answers ([r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76992763/8245406), [rps1227](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76992852/8245406)) as a function with the dots argument as an argument.

```r
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(c("a","b","c"),c("p","q","r"),c("x","y","z"),c("l","m","n")))

library(data.table)

fun <- function(x, ...) Reduce(paste0, x[c(...)])

# any of do.call or Reduce will call 'paste0'
# on the columns .SD/.SDcols
fun_dt <- function(x, ...) {
  # df[, do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = c(...)]
  df[, Reduce(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = c(...)]
}

i <- 1
j <- 2
k <- 4

# two columns
fun(df, i, j)
#>  [1] "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq"
#> [16] "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp"
#> [31] "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr"
#> [46] "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq"
#> [61] "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp"
#> [76] "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr"

# three columns
fun(df, i, j, k)
#>  [1] "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl" "brl" "crl" "apl" "bpl" "cpl"
#> [13] "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl" "brl" "crl" "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql"
#> [25] "arl" "brl" "crl" "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm"
#> [37] "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apm" "bpm" "cpm"
#> [49] "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn"
#> [61] "arn" "brn" "crn" "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn"
#> [73] "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn"

# now for package data.table
dt <- df
setDT(dt)
# two columns
fun_dt(df, i, j)
#>  [1] "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq"
#> [16] "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp"
#> [31] "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr"
#> [46] "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq"
#> [61] "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp" "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr" "ap" "bp" "cp"
#> [76] "aq" "bq" "cq" "ar" "br" "cr"

# three columns
fun_dt(df, i, j, k)
#>  [1] "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl" "brl" "crl" "apl" "bpl" "cpl"
#> [13] "aql" "bql" "cql" "arl" "brl" "crl" "apl" "bpl" "cpl" "aql" "bql" "cql"
#> [25] "arl" "brl" "crl" "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm"
#> [37] "apm" "bpm" "cpm" "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apm" "bpm" "cpm"
#> [49] "aqm" "bqm" "cqm" "arm" "brm" "crm" "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn"
#> [61] "arn" "brn" "crn" "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn"
#> [73] "apn" "bpn" "cpn" "aqn" "bqn" "cqn" "arn" "brn" "crn"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>